# citadel not receiving email for webmaster, postmaster and hostmaster

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-server, apache-2.4, citadel

The SSL certificate for a server I setup a year ago (to be read as: not familiar with its setup anymore) has expired and I need to get a new one. In order to do that, I need to get a code that I can have emailed ONLY at one of the following:

- `hostmaster@<mydomain>`
- `postmaster@<mydomain>`
- `webmaster@<mydomain>`

The mail server is the latest version of citadel, running on top of Ubuntu and Apache2.

The problem is that those addresses are not receiving any emails (they have separate accounts). I've tried sending from my email addresses to confirm and they're not showing up in the inbox (no daemon failure message coming back either).

**HOWEVER**:

- I can send emails from them fine.
- I can receive emails on ANY OTHER email account on that server.
- I can send an email from `webmaster@<mydomain>` to `admin@<mydomain>` and it shows up fine, but if I try it the other way around it doesn't work.

I thought it might be a rule for the user but there's none showing in `Advanced / View/edit server-side mail filters` looking from the webmaster account. Is there maybe a config file I could check?

**Any idea why these 3 accounts could not be receiving emails and how I can fix it?**

Comment: What do the mail logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, messages to `postmaster` are posted in the `Aide` room, where all administrators can read them. You can [change this if necessary](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/faq:everydayuse:postmaster_and_co).

For other addresses, simply [add these to your vCard](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/faq:systemadmin:how_do_i_configure_email_aliases_for_a_user) and you will begin receiving mail for them.

Comment: It was not showing up in the Aide room but the aliases worked. Thanks!